# Pascal Triangle c# code space complexity

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, interview-questions

can you give me your impression of my implementation of Pascal triangle problem?
I'm especially interested in space complexity evaluation
thank you all!

```
public List<List<int>> generate(int A)
{
    List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

    int currenctRowLength = 1;
    List<int> previousRow = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    {
        List<int> row = new List<int>();
        row.Add(1);
        currenctRowLength = i + 1;
        int j = 1;
        while (j < currenctRowLength - 1)
        {
            row.Add(previousRow[j] + previousRow[j - 1]);
            j++;
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            row.Add(1);
        }            

        previousRow=row;
        result.Add(row);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) `space complexity` reads [*asymptotic analysis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) to me: what *operations* are to be supported with what *constraints* satisfied? My take: don't fret about ("per item") storage required(yet): if it takes more space than you are willing to pay, it will be taxing your patience in the first place.

Comment: (`my implementation of [a] problem` reads funny.)

Comment: I was wondering if there is a better solution, I guess there is.

Comment: You didn't edit into your code/question what interface the result is to support - `IList<IList<ulong>>pascalTriangle()` would open up a lot of possibilities `List<List<int>>(int)` obstructs. (Note: it wouldn't even need a *numberOfRows* parameter (what the hell is `A`?))

Comment: I agree but in this case the return type was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think greybeard was trying to say, unless you are know that memory consumption/allocation costs are a serious concern, then this code is fine from a memory point of view. The space-complexity is the same as the output (quadratic in `A`), so you can't do better than that.

There a couple of small things to be said:

- as GreyBeard says, `A` is completely meaningless, and should really have a `lowerCamelCase` name as a parameter (e.g. `dimension`, `size`?); `generate` ought to be `GeneratePascalTriangle` or something meaningful (public -> `UpperCamelCase`) ([msdn reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions))
- `currenctRowLength` should be `currentRowLength`, and should only be defined inside the `for` loop (i.e. where it is assigned); I like that this is its own variable.
- you are using a `while` loop over `j`, when a `for` could be more readable (simply because people are used to reading for-loops), and doesn't leak `j` into the outer scope.
- `List<List<int>>` is a pretty horrid type to be returning: much better to have `IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<T>>` if the return value is meant to be immutable (which is assignable from `List<List<T>>` or `T[][]`).
- I'd be inclined to initialise `previousRow` to `null`, rather than an empty list: it isn't read until `i == 2`; assigning it to a 'meaningful' value is defensive and only can work to obscure bugs in the rest of the code.

### Mindless Performance Musing

If memory usage/allocations/GC hammering *is* a real concern, then you can improve matters by not using resizing lists. You havn't given us any idea of what the code is actually meant to do, so it's a bit hard to suggest an alternative, but you could either use arrays (which obvious are non-dynamic) or you can preserve the signature by creating lists with a given initial capacity with the [`.ctor(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. Note that this will give a performance benefit, but change the time-complexity (which is also quadratic in `A`).

### Code

Putting all of that together (and using arrays instead of lists, because mindless performance is fun, and I don't think it harms the readability here much):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Generates a pascal triangle with the given number of rows
/// </summary>
public static IReadOnlyList<IReadOnlyList<int>> GeneratePascalTriangle(int numberOfRows)
{
    int[][] result = new int[numberOfRows][];

    int[] previousRow = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        int currentRowLength = i + 1;

        int[] row = new int[currentRowLength];
        result[i] = row;

        // start and end
        row[0] = 1;
        row[currentRowLength - 1] = 1;

        // middle
        for (int j = 1; j < currentRowLength - 1; j++)
        {
            row[j] = previousRow[j] + previousRow[j - 1];
        }            

        previousRow = row;
    }

    return result;
}
```